# Narrow String Union Type To String Literal Type

Tags: typescript

For simplicity say I have a string Union type like so

```
type StringUnion = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'

// I define an array based on that union
const arr: StringUnion[] = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C']

function getValue(idx: number) {
  return arr[idx]
}

const a = getValue(0)
// Now `a` is of type StringUnion
```

Is there a way or is it even possible to have the return value of `getValue` function to return type `A` instead of type `StringUnion`?

Comment: Is the array a compile-time constant?

Comment: Yes! It wont change at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the array with `as const` so that TypeScript will give it the type `readonly ["A", "B", "B", "C"]`. If you convert `getValue` to a generic function and declare the return type as `(typeof arr)[T]` you can get the desired result:

```
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'] as const

function getValue<T extends number>(idx: T): (typeof arr)[T] {
  return arr[idx]
}

const a = getValue(0)  // -> "A"
```